# How to learn DNA Origami

Tags: dna, bioinformatics, biotechnology

Can you tell me is there any good softwares and tutorials which can be used to learn DNA Origami. I am new to this and want to learn from basics.

Advance thanks for your help

edited: INSILICO

Comment: I am assuming you want to do it *in silico*, right?

Comment: you can also do a little origami DNA... http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0jOapfqVZlo

Comment: @nico yes, my current idea is to do it in insilico..but may be in future i will try to do it in invitro also..it will be helpful if any one can explained both procedure

Answer (score 1):

Try [this](http://cadnano.org/).

> cadnano simplifies and enhances the process of designing three-dimensional DNA origami nanostructures. Through its user-friendly 2D and 3D interfaces it accelerates the creation of arbitrary designs. The embedded rules within cadnano paired with the finite element analysis performed by cando, provide relative certainty of the stability of the structures.

Comment: I would try to read everything from Shawn Douglas's body of work. cadnano is definitely the best start.

Comment: According to Rothemund, the original algorithm in the DNA origami paper is the same and much improved in caDNAno.